# Naming self or this something else, a good idea?

Tags: javascript, python, readability

I'm finding that my code becomes more readable when I make a local reference to this/self, and/or call it something that makes sense in the context. "self" or "this" doesn't really indicate what kind of object we are dealing with, in the same way as "default" or "standard" or "master" is unclear because it's not explicit.

For example, in Python code, instead of naming the instance reference "self", you could name it something else:

```
class User:
    def getFullName(user):
        return user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
```

What are the arguments for naming it self, instead of something more explicit, like "user" in this case?

A similar example in JavaScript when doing a manual mixin:

```
function asUser(obj, name) {
    var user = obj;
    user.name = name;
    return user;
}
```

I guess in JavaScript this is less controversial because there is not strong tradition of using a certain naming, as in the case of "self" in Python.

Comment: In Python: `self` is such an established convention, that I find using anything else extremely surprising. And what if the method interacts with *other* users? `self` is *crystal clear*, you are working on the *current instance*, the one the method is bound to.

Comment: Going against convention *reduces* the amount of information your code conveys even if the variable name is arguably more explicit. A Python programmer sees `self` as the first argument of a method and knows *exactly* what that means. If they see anything *other* than `self` they'll waste time trying to figure out 1) are you doing something different? 2) apparently not, so why did you break the convention?

Comment: Good points and I agree to some extent. But I also feel that.. do you really need to know that you are working on the current instance? You have code that operates on a user object. Does it really matter if that user object is the "instance" or some other user object?

Comment: If it doesn't matter whether you are working with an instance or some other object, why not through out OO entirely and just change `user.getFullName()` calls to `getFullName(user)`?

Comment: @MagnusWolffelt I think the Python and JS cases are not the same. In Python you name the first parameter of a method `self` to indicate that it's the *object* that got passed in from invoking `object.function()`. In JS I would much rather write `var user = this` than `var that = this` or some nonsense. In the JS case there is no agreed-upon convention anyway (`that`, `self`, `_this`, etc.). And the point of aliasing `this` is to have a normal lexically scoped variable that doesn't disappear inside a closure (so why not name it like one?). We don't have that problem in Python.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what a co-incidence! I asked a meta question on the same topic just few minutes ago [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/303082/81282). Hope you could shed some light on it.

Comment: @vivek: you are taking my comment out of context here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general I feel it might make your code **less readable**. Simply because inside different classes you're going to use **different** words to reference the instance. I refactor a lot of code for a living and a `this`, `self` or even `_this` is immediately scanned by me as the reference to the instance.

This may not exactly fit your requirements but in JavaScript we do have to frequently rename `this`! **The this keyword loses context inside callbacks and refers to window / global!**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this?lq=1
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
var _this = this;
var self = this;
```

Is how most JS libraries roll!

Answer (score 4):

This is a huge mistake.  `self` is a well-worn convention in Python and so any Python programmer who encounters this code is going to immediately be confused.  Any experienced programmer will see `self` and will instinctively think "I am looking at a method definition and this particular line is accessing an attribute of the object".

Name it something else, and you've lost the advantage of that instinct.  For a two line method as above, this will produce a few minutes head scratching.  If the method is a complex one, maybe twenty lines, it will produce a lot more confusion, and the average python programmer will repeatedly end up thinking "oh wait...`user` is the `self` object."  That will waste time if nothing else.

Confusion will multiply if any code outside the object uses `user` as a name, which is, of course, the obvious thing to name an object of type `User` *outside* the class.  This means you will continually be thinking "Oh wait, am I inside the class or not?"

Speaking as a long term C++ and then Python coder, your first example just seems weird.  My brain does not even want to think of it as a method despite the fact that it knows it is.  `user` looks like something being "passed in" from outside the object, and it is actual mental work to realize that it is not something external to the object.

Convention is massively important in code readability.  It's why we have style guides.  One thing that earns python's reputation for readability is that it has a clearly defined style guide that most conform to.  `self` is a part of that.

Comment: Not to mention that any editor worth its salt will highlight `self` but not `user`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree that it's a huge mistake. And is it really that important to know whether you are "inside the class"?

I could argue that it is mental work to map self to the containing class name.

A well chosen self-name reads more naturally than self, in my opinion.